# Hosting a Asp.net Application In IIS-7 via Web service C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I tried the below codes...and its working perfectly when i am running this codes from a windows application. But the same code is not getting executed by web service..its copy the folder but wwwroot directory but not hosting it on the IIS..Please help me out..

```
    public void HostInSerevr(string client4)
    {
        try
        {
            string strWebsitename = client4; // abc
            string strApplicationPool = "DefaultAppPool";  // set your deafultpool :4.0 in IIS
            string strhostname = client4.ToLower() + ".clouddunk.com"; //abc.com
            //string stripaddress = txtipaddress.Text;// ip address
            string bindinginfo = "*:" + "80:" + strhostname;
            //string bindinginfo = strhostname;
            string websitePath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot" + "\\" + "ATP_" + client4;
            //=@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot"

            //check if website name already exists in IIS
            Boolean bWebsite = IsWebsiteExists(strWebsitename);
            if (!bWebsite)
            {
                //Site mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add(strWebsitename.ToString(), "http", bindinginfo, @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourWebsite");
                Site mySite = serverMgr.Sites.Add(strWebsitename.ToString(), "http", bindinginfo, websitePath);
                mySite.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = strApplicationPool;
                mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Enabled = true;
                mySite.TraceFailedRequestsLogging.Directory = @"C:\inetpub\CustomLog";
                mySite.ServerAutoStart = true;

                serverMgr.CommitChanges();

                string path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";

                //DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                //FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.File").Where(p => p.Extension == ".File").ToArray();
                //if (files.Count() > 0)
                //{
                string writeText = "127.0.0.1" + " " + strhostname;
                File.AppendAllText(path, Environment.NewLine + writeText);
                //}
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public bool IsWebsiteExists(string strWebsitename)
    {
        Boolean flagset = false;
        SiteCollection sitecollection = serverMgr.Sites;
        foreach (Site site in sitecollection)
        {
            if (site.Name == strWebsitename.ToString())
            {
                flagset = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flagset = false;
            }
        }
        return flagset;
    }
```

Comment: What error is occuring here ?

Comment: there is no error inthis code. It's been executed perfectly and all the task is being done except the IIS hosting code(no error occurs but its does not get hosted.)

public void HostInSerevr(string client4)
{}